# For a German residence, is there a difference between investing U.S-based or Eurozone-based ETFs?

Tags: taxes, etf, capital-gains-tax

For a German residence, if you compare investing in identical two bond ETFs, one is in the US and one is in the Eurozone area, from a taxation perspective, which one is cheaper?

Comment: I have no idea if one is cheaper. Buying ETFs that are issued in Europe, are easier to handle as the bank cares for the taxes.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler I'm not using a bank, so that is not relevant.